# How to use @SpringBootTest class mockbean in test class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-test

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
class ServiceIntegTest {

}
```

```
class TestConfig {

@MockBean
RandomExecutor randomExecutor


}
```

I want to use `RandomExecutor` mock bean in `ServiceIntegTest` class, how to do it ?

I am not mocking methods of the bean in `TestConfig` class itself, because in `ServiceIntegTest` class there are various tests in which methods of `RandomExecutor` have to behave in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

You use a MockBean as you would a `@Mock` It just get injected into a spring context you're using for your test.

```
@SpringBootTest
class ServiceIntegTest {
  @MockBean RandomExecutor randomExecutor;

  // this service gets autowired from your actual implementation,
  // but injected with the mock bean you declared above
  @Autowired
  YourService underTest;

  @Test
  void verifyValueUsed() {
    final int mockedValue = 5;
    when(randomExecutor.getThreadCount()).thenReturn(mockedValue);
    int result = underTest.getExecutorThreads();

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(mockedValue);
  }

  @Test
  void verifyExecutorCalled() {
    underTest.performAction("argument");
    verify(randomExecutor).executorMethod("argument");
  }
}
```

Comment: Several other test methods in ServiceIntegTest already use TestConfig. I tried this       [code] @SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)`
class ServiceIntegTest {
@MockBean RandomExecutor randomExecutor
} [/code] I get duplicate mock definiton error

Comment: @AjaySabarish You can define a bean in your test configuration, but that will be just a normal Spring bean that will get injected into your service. You can use either the mock bean annotation in your test, or a proper bean declaration in your configuration. You don't want to use a `@MockBean` in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I didn't get your idea, are you suggesting something like this ? https://pastebin.com/H8dJHbhC I am getting NullPointerException at the line of stubbing.

Comment: @AjaySabarish I'm suggesting what I wrote in my answer and not declare anything to do with this in your TestConfig at all.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to `@MockBean` in your config, you have to do it in the test class. Then you can mock it in some test classes and use a real instance in others.

Have a look at a basic usage of `@MockBean`:
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3543268/junit-5-tutorial-part-2-unit-testing-spring-mvc-with-junit-5.html

Comment: Yes but the config is already present and several test classes use it already, I am just adding new test methods in 1 class and I need to alter the behaviour of 1 method of RandomExecutor in different ways using Mockito to cover various branches. Is there any way to do it without modifying the config class ?